# Repeated rudeness from a specific user

Tags: discussion

There is not enough space to write this in a flag, nor the capacity to include screenshots. I am going to block out instances of the user's name in order to keep him or her anonymous.

I believe something should be done about this user's repetitive misconduct.
I have successfully made multiple flags against this person that were marked as "helpful", for example:

[image]

and:

[image]

There was another flag where the user told a brand new user that the way he was thinking about the problem was "horrible", and I was told that my rude/abusive flag was so trivial that I should have edited the question immediately:

[image]

Considering these three flags, I'm sure other users also raised helpful flags against this user.

A first time brand new user was met with unwelcoming comments by this user, and in fact wrote "***He was so rude and arrogant man absolutely insulting what a coward deleting his comments no backbone to stick to his convictions.***"

Now I've raised a flag because he wrote "How on earth would that be..."

[image]

which is in violation of at least one part of the code of conduct as far as I see:

"no subtle put-downs"

[image]

[image]

"How on Earth..." is a euphemism for the far more common "how the hell...". I do not like seeing this phrase and it makes me extremely uncomfortable.

The same flagged comment contains another subtle put-down:

[image]

which ***implies*** that the answer was not factual. Is there not a more polite way of discussing possible improvements to an answer than using these subtle put-downs?

I have flagged the user's comment, and at least one moderator has already seen the flag, and nothing has been done about this repetitive bad conduct which is in violation of the Code of Conduct.

I wonder if the community believes that some attempt should be made to mitigate the rudeness in this person's comments?

Comment: **This post is not useful for future readers.** The problems *have been brought to the attention of the moderators*. A detailed public, official *answer cannot be expected*, as the moderators actions regarding the problem will/might *include private disciplinary actions* against users. **To prevent speculations/privacy violations**, I am voting to close this post.

Comment: @MEE, would it be a bad idea for you to participate in the main site a bit more rather than only participating in our Meta? I never asked for a "detailed, official, answer" to be expected. I asked if the community believes that some attempt should be made to mitigate this user's rudeness. This documentation of what happened is important to keep and update so that the problem doesn't happen to other users. Your reason to vote to close seems invalid.

Comment: [1] @user1271772 I don't think it's up to you to assess my participiation in meta/main. If you want to discuss with me, why I don't participiate in main let me know and I can invite you to a chat room. Regarding the closure of this post: We don't know what user you are talking about (and this is good!). Not every user knows/can know what contents you are talking about. Moderator activities against users are intentionally private. Therefore there is nothing the community can do. I have looked into some chatrooms and I know that at least one mod is aware of the situation. ...

Comment: [2] ... To protect the user from speculations I decided to VOTE to close this question. It will be up to the community to follow or not to follow my "proposal".

Comment: @MEE: You do not have to be rude now. About not knowing the user, you are not meant to. I deliberately spent LOTS of time making the user anonymous. You say "Therefore there is nothing the community can do" but that is 100% false. The community can say "yes, I agree that this behavior is bad and something needs to be done about it!". Yes there's a mod that knows about it because I raised a lot of flags but (1) the mods allowed it to get to the stage where a brand new user was attacked and "insulted" (I'm using his/her words here) despite being able to prevent that, and (2) after raising the

Comment: flags, not much has changed. Finally, there is no possibility for anyone to find out who the user is.

Comment: I agree that attacking a brand new user is extremely bad but I think personally think this meta post is not useful and used my vtc-privilege to inform the community about my decision. This is nothing hostile against you but just a neutral information by me. Oh and I'd rather not continue this discussion here in the comments. If you wish so, we could use a (gallery) chatroom...

Comment: @MEE, the brand new first time user said: "He was so rude and arrogant man absolutely insulting what a coward deleting his comments no backbone to stick to his convictions." .... you want that type of thing to continue? The brand new user has never come back.

Comment: @MEE: You say it was not meant to be hostile against me but it is, unfortunately. Also you seem to be out of line for voting to close. "This question does not appear to be about Quantum Computing Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center."   It ***is*** about QCSE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84814/discussion-between-mee-and-user1271772).

Comment: Given the formulation *"He was so rude and arrogant man absolutely insulting what a coward deleting his comments no backbone to stick to his convictions."*, there is a possibility that the brand new user him/herself has not been particularly kind. I'm not sure how you make your judgement of what happened based solely on that statement.

Answer (score 6):

> [in a flag]: You send me warnings and ban me from here for a week, please do it to [censored]
>
> I have flagged the user's comment [...] and nothing has been done about this repetitive bad conduct

Moderator communications with users --- especially warnings, the details of any current suspension, and the existence of any past suspensions --- are kept confidential, for [good reasons discussed elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293213/280545). Therefore you do not know, and in all likelihood *will never* know, whether the disciplinary messages you are requesting have been sent. If what you're looking for is confirmation that your concerns are being taken seriously, you've got it: your flags have been cleared as "helpful."

On other moderated communities on the internet, you see advice to respond to "fiamo," an acronym for "flag it and move on." The second half is important.

I'm a little unclear on what you're hoping to achieve with this meta post. The moderators are constrained from telling you whether your requests have been acted upon.  The user whose behavior you dislike cannot respond and retain their privacy. And since you've quoted your (confidential) flags rather than any of the offending content, others in the community can only guess whether they are discussing the same (possibly removed) troublesome content as you are.  You've made it clear that you are upset, and it's plausible that you have a good reason to be upset, but I don't see how any response here is going to satisfy you. I think the best possible outcome of this question is that more people get fighty with each other, which is not good for a community.

One thing that you might consider, if you really want to follow up, would be to (politely) ping a moderator in chat: "I have a question about your response to my flag on http://whatever." On Physics we have occasionally made a private room with a user to have a private discussion that's more involved than the flag and flag-reply system permits. I don't know if the QC mods would be open to this; mods are people too, and people are busy.